# Change value of each element by linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to do sth like this in LINQ:

```
int[] d = new int[c.Length + 1];     
int e = 1;
                d.ToList().ForEach(r => 
                {
                    r = e;
                    e++;
                });
```

?.
When I did this, it returned me sequence of zeros.
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would, for two reasons:

- You're creating a copy of the original array as a `List<int>`, and then trying to modify the `List<int>`. That wouldn't modify the array.
- Your lambda expression changes the value of the parameter, that's all. It doesn't modify the list.

Basically, LINQ is for *querying*. Don't even bother trying to do this: use a `for` loop if you want to modify the collection.

However, if your aim is to *produce* an array of 1...(c.Length+1), just use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, c.Length + 1).ToArray();
```